# What's the use of the [tex] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [tex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex) tag currently has only 3 questions (only 2 till yesterday :)), and all of them have been closed. Moreover, I imagine that any question that fits the tag would be more appropriate for TeX.SE anyway.

So why do we have this tag? Can someone give an example of a question that fits the tag and yet would be considered acceptable for this site?

*Update (Oct 8): The tag is now deleted; see Jeff's answer for details.*

Comment: After posting this question, I noticed a related post: [1850](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/should-the-latex-tag-stay). Please close this question if it is considered a duplicate (I am not sure about it myself).

Comment: I before voted to delete such questions and remove the tag. I had lost 10 flag weight on such flag. However, now I have the power to vote for deletion. And I do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed; I migrated one question to tex.se and deleted the other.

The tag should auto-remove itself within 24 hours.

Comment: Maybe we can prevent the tag from ever being created again?